# Qt creator 5.7 installation in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt-creator

I was using an old version of Qt creator, then I downloaded Qt-creator5.7 and installed manually in my home folder. I couldn’t find any executable with name qt/ qtcreator in the home/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin. How do I launch qtcreator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Qt 5.6.1. And I had installed it manually too. The Qt Creator executable file is located in 'Tools' directory and not in the Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin directory.
First, through the terminal go the directory where the executable file is, and then using './' run it. Ex: ./qtcreator